# Remembering objects in array already rendered

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm going to list up some news in a scrollbar.
What I managed to do so far is to re-render the component to display more news upon scrollbar reaches bottom.

At start my initial state 25 news. Then for every scroll, I just add another 25 news. What I noticed was that my component was very slow upon re-rendering of more news. I suspect that it might be because of its rendering "already-rendered" news from scratch.

Is it possible to make already rendered news to stay in memory or something, atleast not being re-rendered and just re-render new news?

Remembering objects in array already rendered

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `PureComponent`. The React docs state the following:

> React.PureComponent is similar to React.Component. The difference between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a shallow prop and state comparison.
>
> If your React component’s render() function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a performance boost in some cases.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Turning your `ListItem` components into `PureComponet` could help with performance, because React would not rerender those components if the props passed to it are the same.

Comment: Would this also apply on for example array as a state with multiple objects?

Comment: I would have to see some code samples to be able to answer that question :)